# Indexing the return value of a parameterless function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've recently come across what I believe to be quite an obscure language feature while writing some vb.net code.

The feature is that if the function that you are calling does not receive any parameters and you attempt to call it with a parameter **(And expect to see an error appear, or at least be given a compile time error!)**, it will get implicitly converted to an attempt to index the return value of the function instead.

The below code example is from a new vb.net form project created in visual studio.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Call GetCaption()


        Me.Text = GetCaption() ' The caption of the form is 'this is my new form'

        Me.Text = GetCaption(1) ' The caption of the form is 'h'

        Me.Text = GetString(2) 'The caption of the form is '2'
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCaption() As String
        Return "This is my new form"
    End Function

    Private Function GetString() As String()

        Dim x As String() = {"", "0", "2"}

        Return x

    End Function
End Class
```

I have found the following documentation that mentions that 'If there are no arguments, you can optionally omit the parentheses. However, using the parentheses makes your code easier to read.' Available Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1wey3ak2.aspx

I have also found documentation about the error that you receive when you try to attempt to this with a function that has a return type that cannot be indexed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1wwy0we(v=vs.140).aspx

I cannot however find any documentation that discusses this functionality, or that mentions the implicit conversion to indexing the function return, instead of attempting to pass parameters to a function that doesn't receive any.

Any ideas?

Comment: The returns are strings.  Strings are character arrays.  So `GetCaption(1)` is the second char in that string.  If the method did take an arg, `GetCaption(arg)(1)` would do the same

Comment: For example it's equivalent to, `Dim caption As String = GetCaption` then `Me.Text = caption(1)`

Comment: `(1)` isn't a parameter to `GetCaption` it's an index on the string returned from `GetCaption` hence why you end up with _h_. In your `GetString` method you are returning an array and so `(2)` is the index of that array.

Comment: The VB-ism of being able to omit parens on functions means that `GetCaption()(1)` would do the same thing

Comment: @Plutonix and that would be a sensible way to write it as it's quite clear to anybody who is reading it. `GetCaption(1)` could be interpreted as passing a parameter by the reader until they look closer at the method.

Comment: @Plutonix,@Jinx88909,@JonSkeet  Thanks for your responses. I understand what it's doing, my question was more, why? because the code is not clear at all when you use GetCaption(1). It would be much better and clearer if you were forced to do GetCaption()(1). I wonder why you are allowed to omit function parenthesis if it could lead to confusion like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling it with a parameter.  The compiler knows the method doesnt take an argument, so it doesnt try to pass it as such.  The return of `GetCaption()` is a string, and a string is a character array which can be indexed so the code is fetching the Nth character from the returned string.  Equivalent methods would be:

```
Me.Text = GetCaption(1)   ' second char, arrays are zero based
Me.Text = GetCaption.Chars(1)   
Me.Text = GetCaption.ElementsAt(1)
```

Those implement the VB-ism of being able to omit function parens; including them makes it a bit clearer that the code is actually indexing the return value:

```
Me.Text = GetCaption()(1) 
Me.Text = GetCaption().Chars(1)   
Me.Text = GetCaption().ElementsAt(1)
```

In the end, the title is correct: the code is indexing the return value.  There is no error because strings can be indexed.

Comment: Marked as answer for clear explanation of what is happening in the code, although all comments have been helpful. I still wonder why you are allowed to omit parenthesis if it can lead to confusion like this though.

Comment: VB lets you do all sorts of things that are not always a good idea (Option Strict Off, for example).  Just because you can do a thing doesnt mean you should do that thing.  Many of thos VB-isms are meant to make it easy for "dabblers" to get code to compile